# How to search two datagrids using one button and one textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a code that lets me search the data grid, it was working fine until I added another datagrid. Now whenever I press search it gives me an error saying **"Cannot find column [Requestor]"**. Both my datagrids data has the requestor columns.

The first table in the first datagridview is named *draft_table*

The second table in the second datagridview is named *main_table*

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Try
        Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
        Dim DV2 As New DataView(dbDataSet2)
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Requestor Like '%{0}%' or Vendor Like '%{0}%'", srchtxt.Text)
        DV2.RowFilter = String.Format("Requestor Like '%{0}%' or Vendor Like '%{0}%'", srchtxt.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
        DataGridView2.DataSource = DV2
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

[Screenshot of the two datagrids and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMzmG.png)

[Screenshot of the *main_table* in the MYSQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZv9D.png)

[Screenshot of the *draft_table* in the MYSQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep85a.png)

Comment: Firstly, don't create new `DataViews` and then rebind the grids.  When you bind a `DataTable`, the data you see comes from the `DefaultView`, which is a `DataView`.  You can just set the `RowFilter` property of that existing `DataView`.  Better still, bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid, then set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: If you are getting an error message telling you that there's no column with that name then there's no column with that name.  If you think there is then you are mistaken.  There's no way for us to determine why you're making that mistake based on the information you have provided.

Comment: OT, maybe use some meaningful names for things, rather than generic names that tell you nothing about what they are actually for.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry for the incomplete informations. This is my first time asking a question here. I have included photos that shows the column names in the two datagrids and and the error, as well as the columns inside my MYSQL Workbench.

Comment: Instead of assuming that it is there based on external information, how about you actually look to see what is there?  Loop through the `Columns` of the `DataTable` and check the `ColumnName` of each one.  For all we know, you've never even populated those particular `DataTables`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I forgot to say, I have 1 more form that uses the search button but with only 1 datagrid and it is working. It only errors when tgere is two datagrid